# Iframe load only once on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I manage to incorporate an iframe resizing script by DynamicDrive and it works nicely.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/iframessi2.htm

I set it up to load only on mouseover..

`onmouseover="javascript:loadintoIframe('myframe', 'http://mysite.com/page.php)"`

However, I need it to only load once instead of reloading on every hover.

I've tried this but I think I have to add something to javascript but not sure.

`onclick="this.value = '';this.onclick=null;"`

Comment: Have you thought about something simple like a flag? `var loaded = false;` and then when you mouse over, check if `loaded` is false, and if it is, initialize the iframe and then set `loaded` to `true` so it doesn't fire again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you want to keep the onmouseover handler delcared as an attribute, you could try:

```
onmouseover="javascript:if(loadintoIframe) {loadintoIframe('myframe', 'http://mysite.com/page.php); loadintoIframe=null;}"
```

The second time it gets called, it doesn't do anything

Personally, I prefer using [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can do this...

```
$('element').bind('mouseover', function(event) { 
   // load your iframe here 
   $(this).unbind(event);
});
```

The following will work as well...

```
$('element').one('mouseover', function() { 
    // load your iframe here 
});
```